# REGEX validation ignored unless separate REGEX validation fires

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I am working to validate the format of a string to 4 letters-3 zeroes-4 letters.  On it's own, this REGEX() works fine: `OR( /* check the leftmost 4 for any digit */ REGEX(LEFT(String__c,1),"[0-9]{1}"), REGEX(RIGHT(LEFT(String__c,2),1),"[0-9]{1}"), REGEX(RIGHT(LEFT(String__c,3),1),"[0-9]{1}"), REGEX(RIGHT(LEFT(String__c,3),1),"[0-9]{1}"), /* check the rightmost 4 for any digit */ REGEX(RIGHT(String__c,1),"[0-9]{1}"), REGEX(LEFT(RIGHT(String__c,2),1),"[0-9]{1}"), REGEX(LEFT(RIGHT(String__c,3),1),"[0-9]{1}"), REGEX(LEFT(RIGHT(String__c,4),1),"[0-9]{1}"))`
As it happens, there is an older format that is also valid, and when I include this ^ in the other validation it's ignored; *unless* I have this ^^ in it's own, separate validation rule; then they both fire.

`OR(
/* Not just 5 numbers */
AND(LEN(String__c)==5,
NOT(ISNUMBER(String__c))
),

/* NOT 7 characters being an upper/lower combination of 'LX' and 5 numbers */
AND(LEN(String__c)==7,
OR(NOT(UPPER(LEFT(String__c,2))=="LX"),
NOT(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(String__c,5)))
)
),

/* not value with a digit in first- or last 4 characters */
OR( /* check the leftmost 4 for any digit */
REGEX(LEFT(String__c,1),"[0-9]{1}"),
REGEX(RIGHT(LEFT(String__c,2),1),"[0-9]{1}"),
REGEX(RIGHT(LEFT(String__c,3),1),"[0-9]{1}"),
REGEX(RIGHT(LEFT(String__c,3),1),"[0-9]{1}"),
/* check the rightmost 4 for any digit */
REGEX(RIGHT(String__c,1),"[0-9]{1}"),
REGEX(LEFT(RIGHT(String__c,2),1),"[0-9]{1}"),
REGEX(LEFT(RIGHT(String__c,3),1),"[0-9]{1}"),
REGEX(LEFT(RIGHT(String__c,4),1),"[0-9]{1}")),

/* not 13 characters and in the format azAZ-###-azAZ */
AND(
LEN(String__c)==13,
NOT(REGEX(String__c,"[a-zA-Z]{4}-[0]{3}-[a-zA-Z]{4}"))
),

/* or anything not matching 5-, 7- or 13 characters */
AND(NOT(ISBLANK(String__c)),
NOT(LEN(String__c)==5),
NOT(LEN(String__c)==7),
NOT(LEN(String__c)==13))

)`

Comment: NOTE: Some of the commented lines /* */ appear incorrectly formatted; they are fine and validated in the actual formula.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use a full regex for the whole value? E.g. `REGEX('\w{4}\d{3}\w{4}')`. What you have done is very complex for what looks like no reason. You can allow for different formats easily using the pipe (`|`) character. Have a look at regex101.com or other resources about regex.

Comment: Thank you Phil; there are many resources for REGEX, with or w/o Salesforce, and as there are always many ways to approach a problem, it can get complicated.  I will give yours a try and report back.